# How to install Google Chrome on Ubuntu server 22.04

Tags: 22.04, dpkg, google-chrome

I have a problem installing Google Chrome on Ubuntu 22.04 (VPS) with an AMD processor. I also tried just in case on Ubuntu 22.04 with an Intel processor). I have rigorously followed the procedure of some forums that told me how to install Google Chrome.

```
sudo apt update 
sudo apt upgrade 
sudo apt install wget 
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb 
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

I have the following error.

[image: Capture image error #1]

I have tried uninstalling everything again with the following commands suggested in other forums without success:

```
dpkg --list | grep google 
sudo apt --purge remove google-chrome-stable 
sudo apt-get autoremove 
sudo apt-get autoclean 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get -f install
```

I have also tried installing a previous stable version: 07-google-chrome-stable_114.0.5735.90-1_amd64.deb, but it also gives me an error indicating precisely this package:

[image: Capture image error console]

I tried to install it again, but I kept getting the same error.

Comment: This is almost certainly not the root of your problem, but is there any reason that you're downloading the .deb file directly rather than adding the Google Chrome repository to apt?  By doing so, you'll get updated versions of Chrome as they're released, rather than having to check regularly and download/install manually.  And given the rate of security fixes these days, automatic updates may be best.

Comment: Right after failing to install, please try `dmesg | tail -n 24`. This looks like OOM.

Comment: Indeed , this looks like OOM, or it could be a corrupt .deb package that you can redownload. @klode The Chrome and Edge .debs will automatically install their APT repository, so this way is somewhat ok